# Mailgun API cURL Using HTML, Does it accept head and body tags?

Tags: linux, curl, mailgun

I am trying to send an email using Mailgun API through curl,  I have an html email so all I did was change text to html from the sample given. I added my template but for some reason I notice it doesn't accept head and body tags, right?

I have the url with the newsletter please help me http://bit.ly/10B63PU

Here on the documentation the sample code for sending with api:

http://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned I had to use --form-string not just replace text with html. The example below is directly from mailgun, before they only listed the text version for sending mail.

http://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples

```
 curl -s --user 'api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0' \
  https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages \
  -F from='Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>' \
  -F to='foo@example.com' \
  -F cc='bar@example.com' \
  -F bcc='baz@example.com' \
  -F subject='Hello' \
  -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
 --form-string html='<html>HTML version of the body</html>' \
  -F attachment=@files/cartman.jpg \
  -F attachment=@files/cartman.png
```

Comment: Not documented by mailgun. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the HTML payload to pass HTML, otherwise it will assume it is plain text.

```
curl -s --user 'api:key-3ax6xnjp29jd6fds4gc373sgvjxteol0' \
https://api.mailgun.net/v2/samples.mailgun.org/messages \
-F from='Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>' \
-F to=baz@example.com \
-F to=bar@example.com \
-F subject='Hello' \
-F text='Plain text version of my awesome newsletter' \
-F html='<body>My awesome newsletter</body>'
```

Thank you for asking the question - it might not seem as obvious!

Comment: It may work for some but in my case it wasn't working, Chris H. from mailgun stated with cURL using HTML it will need to be input as a form-string.

Comment: Good thinking! --form-string is best indeed.